# Updating fastlane fails: signet requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm unable to update fastlane.

When I execute `fastlane update_fastlane` I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing fastlane:
signet requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0.
```

When I execute `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]`

I'm stuck at fastlane version 2.28.3. I have tried reinstalling fastlane but I still get the same error.

What can be the cause of this issue? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Assuming you pin a version using `Gemfile`, do you get if you run `bundle exec ruby -v` from inside your project's directory? Or are you using rbenv/rvm? Just running `ruby -v` won't necessarily show the version of Ruby that fastlane is using.

Comment: When I ran `bundle exec ruby -v` I got a lower version, 2.2.4.

But I managed to fix it.

I removed my main Fastlane installation and reinstalled it with `sudo gem install fastlane -NV`

And within the project directory I was able to update Fastlane with `bundle update fastlane`

Answer (score 24):

Use this approach.

Remove fastlane from homebrew. Open terminal and run:

```
brew cask uninstall fastlane
```

Install ruby environments. Run in terminal:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo "" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH=${HOME}/homebrew/bin:${PATH}' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
rbenv install 2.6.5
rbenv global 2.6.5
exit
```

Open terminal again and run:

```
gem install fastlane
fastlane -v
```

Inspiration form:
https://hackernoon.com/the-only-sane-way-to-setup-fastlane-on-a-mac-4a14cb8549c8

Comment: Failed to build gem native extension

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install following the steps provided by [gdingenen](https://github.com/gdingenen): https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15467#issuecomment-540964272

1. Delete the .fastlane folder from the user's home folder

   rm -r -df ~/.fastlane
2. Install using gem

   sudo gem install fastlane -NV

Comment: Nope, `sudo gem install fastlane -NV` is failing for me the very same way

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the old ruby with the lastest one.

1. Find the lastest one. Execute ***which ruby***, my result is ***/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby***.
2. Find the old one. It's ***/Users/username/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/ruby***
3. Replace it. Done.